# Picture Box (хочу менять изображение)

Tags: c#

Создаю игру (WindowsForm) есть один вопрос, создал первую картинку , туда поставил прогрес бар , и когда прогрес бар будет максимум хочу менять изображение на другую как это сделать?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Milionater
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadGame();


            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            pictureBox2.Visible = true;

        }

       public void LoadGame()
        {

            int i;
            for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
                progressBar1.Value = i;



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: что пробовали? Сами как то пытались себе помочь решить задачу?

Comment: да например писал , когда Прогресс бар будет максимум , pictureBox1.Visible = false;pictureBox2.Visible = true; но не работал

Comment: 1) Добавьте код в вопрос 2) не работал - это что значит?

Comment: в вопрос, не в комментарий. Вы можете редактировать сой вопрос и добавлять туда информацию

Comment: Почему бы не просто поменять `pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "другая картинка"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто менять `pbox.ImageLocation`, пример

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    PictureBox pbox ;

    public MyForm()
    {
        pbox = new PictureBox();

        this.Width = 400;
        this.Height = 300;

        pbox.Width = 390;
        pbox.Height = 290;

        this.Controls.Add(pbox);

        this.Load+= (sender, args) => Run();
    }

    private async void Run()
    {
        bool closed = false;
        this.FormClosing += (sender, args) => { closed = true;} ;

        var images = new string[] {
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-DmKJZEQcnd0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAEHI/h3KLgqSE1us/photo.jpg?sz=328",
        "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/68b95170cfb1de9a9929b232f232ad94?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
        };

        var count = 0;

        while(!closed)
        {           
            pbox.ImageLocation = images[count % images.Length];
            count++;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Результат

[image: ...]

Answer (score 0):

Вот прямое обращение к файлу **mypicture.jpg**:
`pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("mypicture.jpg");`
Можно так же менять через цикл и т.д.
На примере если имеем данные о файлах (список файлов)
Загружаем его в Массив **images[n]** типа **string** и по циклу выводим:
`for(int i=0; i<images.length; i++) pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("./"+images[i]);`